# OpenXML how to get cell in range

Tags: c#, openxml

Please help me to get cell in range (ex from A:1 to E:11 are all cells in rectangular). 
For now, my ideal is

```
 Worksheet worksheet = GetWorksheet(document, sheetName);
        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        IEnumerable<Cell> cells = sheetData.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c =>
            c.CellReference >= A:1 &&
            c.CellReference <= E:11 &&
            );
        int t = cells.Count();
```

But this code does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It won't be that easy to compare cell's CellReference with a string. And yes, what you are currently doing is wrong. You simply cannot compare `strings` for Higher or Lower in such a way.

You have two options.

Option 1 :

You can take cell reference and break it down. That means separate characters and numbers and then give them values individually and compare

A1 `- > A  and 1  -> Give A =1 so you have  1 and 1`

E11 `-> E and 11 -> Give E = 5 so you have 5 and 11`

So you will need to breakdown the `CellReference` and check the validity for your requirement.

Option 2 :

If you notice above it's simply we take a 2D matrix index `(ex : 1,1 and 5,11 which are COLUMN,ROW format)`. You can simply use this feature in comparison. But catch is you cannot use `LINQ` for this, you need to iterate through rows and columns. I tried to give following example code, try it

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("PATH", true))
    {
        //Get workbookpart
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

        // Extract the workbook part
        var stringtable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

        //then access to the worksheet part
        IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts;

        foreach (WorksheetPart WSP in worksheetPart)
        {
            //find sheet data
            IEnumerable<SheetData> sheetData = WSP.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>();

            int RowCount = 0;
            int CellCount = 0;

            // This is A1
            int RowMin = 1;
            int ColMin = 1;

            //This is E11              
            int RowMax = 11;
            int ColMax = 5;

            foreach (SheetData SD in sheetData)
            {
                foreach (Row row in SD.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    RowCount++; // We are in a new row

                    // For each cell we need to identify type
                    foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        // We are in a new Cell
                        CellCount++;

                        if ((RowCount >= RowMin && CellCount >= ColMin) && (RowCount <= RowMax && CellCount <= ColMax))
                        {

                            if (cell.DataType == null && cell.CellValue != null)
                            {
                                // Check for pure numbers
                                Console.WriteLine(cell.CellValue.Text);
                            }
                            else if (cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.Boolean)
                            {
                                // Booleans
                                Console.WriteLine(cell.CellValue.Text);
                            }
                            else if (cell.CellValue != null)
                            {
                                // A shared string
                                if (stringtable != null)
                                {
                                    // Cell value holds the shared string location
                                    Console.WriteLine(stringtable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text)).InnerText);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("A broken book");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    // Reset Cell count
                    CellCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This actually work. I tested.

Comment: Thanks KcDoD so much. But why my stringtable is always null at if (stringtable != null). I use your code but change from using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("PATH", true)) to using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true)).

Comment: btw String table is used when you have strings.. May be in your case you have numbers,, but I think solution works fine ? :)

Comment: @Truong Pham You need to accept the answer if you are satisfied.. That's how SO work.. Please refer this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work